# How to display array data in Yii2 GridView using ActiveDataprovider?

Tags: arrays, gridview, yii2

In my db,

```
"email" : [ 
    "amnop@mailinator.com", 
    "abc@mail.com"
],
```

When I `print_r($model->email)`,
it shows

```
Array ( [0] => amnop@mailinator.com [1] => abc@mail.com )
```

In my GridView,

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ----
        'columns' => [
                     -----
                    'price',
                    [
                         'attribute' => 'email',
                          'value' => function($model) {
                              //I need help here... I prefer any foreach function
                        }
                    ],

                    -----
        ]
?>
```

I have to display all the emails in the same column. How to do this?

**Edit**

I use `ActiveDataprovider` as I'm getting the values from my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can just implode emails array:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'email',
     'value' => function($model) {
          if (is_array($model->email)) {
              return implode(', ', $model->email);
          }

          return $model->email;
    }
],
```

Comment: getting an error `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: @BeginnerDev It was a typo, try updated version of answer.

Comment: Are you sure that `$model->email` is an array? Try my update with additional check.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you an array as

```
$data = [
    ['email' => 'amnop@mailinator.com'],
    ['email' => 'abc@mail.com'],
    ...
    ['email' =>  'youremail100@mail.com'],
];
```

you can use an ArrayDataProvider

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [ 'email'],
    ],
]);
```

send the data provider to the as usual

so in gridview you can use ,

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
          ----
          'columns' => [
                       -----
                      'price',
                      [
                           'attribute' => 'email',
                            'value' => function($model) {
                                //I need help here...
                          }
                      ],

                      -----
          ]
  ?>
```

you can take a look at yii2 guide https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers 
and doc https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider

Comment: How can I initialize $data in my search model?

Comment: you comment are question ? or comment ...?  please explain

Comment: The array data provider is for a an array data source .. ad you should build a proper array as   a collection of array with column name and values ..if you need  data from db you can use sqldataprovider or activedataprovider as in guide link

Comment: have you define an array $data with a proper content  .for configure the arrayDataProvider ?? .. i suggest you of  take a deep look at the  guide  .in link  .. and understand  deeply the related  concepet  .